# Serialization issue while returning object having collection of Navigation Objects

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, rest

I am using WCF WebAPI for creating REST service and EF4. While returning an object(of POCO class) which is having NavigationProperty, I am getting following Serialization exception:

> Cannot serialize member Models.Customer.Orders of type System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Models.Order, Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

Following is the POCO class

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
[KnownType(typeof(Order))]
public partial class Customer
{
    #region Primitive Properties
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string CustomerCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Description  { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Comments { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual bool DeleteFlag { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region Navigation Properties

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders
    {
        get
        {
            if (_order == null)
            {
                var newCollection = new FixupCollection<Order>();
                newCollection.CollectionChanged += FixupOrders;
                _order = newCollection;
            }
            return _order;
        }
        set
        {
            if (!ReferenceEquals(_order, value))
            {
                var previousValue = _order as FixupCollection<Order>;
                if (previousValue != null)
                {
                    previousValue.CollectionChanged -= FixupOrders;
                }
                _order = value;
                var newValue = value as FixupCollection<Order>;
                if (newValue != null)
                {
                    newValue.CollectionChanged += FixupOrders;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private ICollection<Order> _order;

    #endregion
    #region Association Fixup

    private void FixupOrders(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Order item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.Customer = this;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (Order item in e.OldItems)
            {
                if (ReferenceEquals(item.Customer, this))
                {
                    item.Customer = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The method in service is as follows:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Customer",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public List<Customer> Get()
{
    CustEntities context = new CustEntities();
    return context.Customer.Include("Orders").ToList();
}
```

Any help in above regard is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can serialize Properties as interfaces in this way, otherwise the deserializer wouldn't know which concrete type to create when the object is deserialized.

Can you change your `ICollection` property to a concrete type like `List<T>`?

Comment: We are creating the POCOs classes using EF T4 template. We don't wanna change the T4 template. Is there any workaround for achieving the above.

Comment: Have you tried adding `[KnownType(typeof(FixupCollection))]` to your Customer class?